# Using atan2 to turn a range from - 1 to 1 into degrees

Tags: c++, math, atan

I'm trying to use atan2 to turn a range of - 1 to 1 into radians and then from radians into degrees.

However atan2(0,1) is equal to 0 when it should be equal 90.0 what am I doing wrong here?

```
float radians = atan2(0, 1);
float degrees = (radians * 180 / PI);
if(radians < 0)
{
    degrees += 360;
}
```

Edit: Okay so i've plugged in the values the right way round this time.

```
float xaxisval = controller->left_stick_x_axis();
float yaxisval = controller->left_stick_y_axis();

// plug values into atan2
float radians = atan2(yaxisval, xaxisval);
float degrees = (radians * 180 / PI);
if (radians < 0)
{
    degrees += 360;
}
```

For context xaxisval and yaxisval are grabbing a value from an analog stick with a max value of 1 to the right and a minimum value of -1 to the left. So when i press the analog stick to the right the yaxisval is equal to 0 and the xaxisval is equal to 1.

This should return 90 degrees, as if you imagine the analog stick as a full 360 degree circle. Up direction is 360/0 right is 90 down is 180 left is 270 etc.

I stuck these values into the debugger and this is what it returned.

```
xaxisval: 1.00000
yaxisval: 0.00000
degrees: 0.00000
```

However I want this direction to come up as 90 degrees it has seemed to jumped up by 90 degrees and i tested the down position and it was equal to 90. Any suggestions?

Debugging Output:
Joystick Up position

```
xaxisval: 0.00000
yaxisval: -1.00000
degrees: 270.00000
```

Joystick Right position

```
xaxisval: 1.00000
yaxisval: 0.00000
degrees: 0.00000
```

Joystick Down position

```
xaxisval: 0.00000
yaxisval: 1.00000
degrees: 90.00000
```

Joystick Left position

```
xaxisval: -1.00000
yaxisval: 0.00000
degrees: 180.00000
```

Joystick North East position

```
xaxisval: 0.929412
yaxisval: 0.592157
degrees: 327.497528
```

Comment: I formatted your code so it is inline in the question. Please don't post code by taking a screenshot of it.

Comment: Sorry I won't in the future I had to rush off for an emergency so decided to post on my phone while I was still in productivity mode. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: You might want to add to the output at the bottom of your post all the samples you tested: joystick up, down, left, right, maybe a few diagonal samples as well. Maybe a few as well with the joystick only tilted in a given direction. This will help with working out exactly how your code is permutating the input data.

Comment: I've added 5 more test samples including one diagonal position, let me know if you need more samples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're passing in the arguments in the wrong order. [`std::atan2`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/atan2) expects the arguments in the order `y,x`, not `x,y`.

Yes, that is incredibly dumb, but it's related to how the tangent function is defined in the first place (which is defined as a ratio of the y-component to the x-component, not the other way around), and like many notational mistakes in mathematics, inertia set in thousands of years ago and you can't push back against it without being a crank.

So write your code like this:

```
float radians = atan2(1, 0);
```

Or, if you want everything as explicit as possible:

```
float x = 0, y = 1;
float radians = atan2(y, x); //Yes, that's the correct order, don't @ me
```

And you'll get the results you expect.

---

Your second problem is that the values that `atan2` correspond to don't match up with the directions you want. What you *want* is a circle where the top is 0°, the right side is 90°, the bottom is 180°, and the left side is 270°. Punching the values into `atan2` is instead going to produce values where the right side is 0°, up is 90°, left is 180°, and down is 270°.

<sup>Also, in comparing with my own hardware, my y-axis is flipped compared to yours. Mine is y+↑, whereas your setup appears to be y-↑</sup>

So if you want to transform the normal `atan2` rotation into the rotation you want, you'll need to transform it like this:

```
float radians = atan2(yaxisval, xaxisval);
float degrees = (radians * 180 / PI);
degrees = 90 - degrees;
if(degrees < 0)
    degrees += 360;
```

Then, all you have to do from there is possibly transform the y-axis depending on whether you *expect* the joystick pushed up to return a positive or negative value. That's up to the domain of your program.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I had to leave my terminal for an emergency but I'll be back in the next half hour to confirm this solution. (also thank you for having a sense of humour and not being mean)

Comment: @Kingpin No problem! I've faced countless software bugs caused by this particular API decision.

Comment: @Xierema Hi, i've just got back and edited my post with an update, could you have a quick look?

Comment: @Kingpin In the future, if fixing your issue reveals a new issue, you should post a second question to avoid invalidating answers that are already posted. I'll take a look though, don't worry about it for this post.

Comment: @Kingpin I updated this answer with some additional information.

Comment: Just to follow this up I got the correct results by making "yaxisval" equal to "-yaxisval" to flip the y axis and then I plugged the values into atan2 the other way around and got a full circle as expected.